# How to auto total/sum for (first input column digits + second input column digits) in cake php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

```
Oven        ON         OFF       Total
........................................
A           20         20         40 (AUTO Sum, array readonly)
B           10         10         20
C           12         30         42  
D           15         15         30
```

Currently i have created the input column for ON and OFF in cakephp. I want to add a total column which will auto sum when i input the ON and OFF column. Now i'm not sure how to do the total function.

Here is my Code:

view ctp file

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('B_On_R01', 
                              array('label' => false, 
                              'error'       => false, 
                              'tabindex'    => 3)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('B_Off_R01', 
                              array('label' => false, 
                              'error'       => false, 
                              'tabindex'    => 3)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('B_Total_R01', 
                              array('readonly' => 'readonly',
                              'label'          => false, 
                              'error'          => false, 
                              'tabindex'       => 3)); ?>
```

Burner Controller

```
if($i < 10) { $j = '0' . $i; } 
else { $j = $i; }
    if(isset($this->request->data['Burner']['B_On_R' . $j]))
        {
        $this->request->data['Burner']['Oven'] = 
        $this->request->data['Burner']['Item_R' . $j];

        $this->request->data['Burner']['B_On'] = 
        $this->request->data['Burner']['B_On_R' . $j];
        }

    else
        if($i < 10) { $j = '0' . $i; } else { $j = $i; }
             if(isset($this->request->data['Burner']['B_Off_R' . $j]))
                {
                $this->request->data['Burner']['Oven'] =   
                $this->request->data['Burner']['Item_R' . $j];

                $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Off'] = 
                $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Off_R' . $j];
                }

        else
            if($i < 10) { $j = '0' . $i; } else { $j = $i; }
               if(isset($this->request->data['Burner']['B_Total_R' . $j]))
                {
                $this->request->data['Burner']['Oven'] = 
                $this->request->data['Burner']['Item_R' . $j];

                $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Total'] =   
                $this->request->data['Burner']['B_Total_R' . $j];
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I really not clear about your question but it seems that `Total` column on your table is unnecessary. You can use `virtual fields`.

**on your model**

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'Total' => 'ON+OFF'
);
```

Now when you fetch records, This `Total` fields will added automatically...